# In python, how would I sort a list of strings where the location of the string comparison changes?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of strings that have 2 dashes separating text like:

```
Wednesday-Morning-Go bowling
Sunday-Really late at night-Sleep
July-Noon-BBQ
```

I'd like to sort the list in alphabetical order in python by the last part of the string--the 2nd dash and on.  Is there a way to do this in python?  E.g. this is what I would want the list to look like after sorting.

```
July-Noon-BBQ
Wednesday-Morning-Go bowling
Sunday-Really late at night-Sleep
```

(I'm using Python 2.6.)

Comment: Hopefully you are not being constricted by your *pythong* :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `key` attribute to `list.sort()`:

```
a = ["Wednesday-Morning-Go bowling", "Sunday-Really late at night-Sleep",
     "July-Noon-BBQ"]
a.sort(key=lambda x: x.split("-", 2)[-1])
print a
```

prints

```
['July-Noon-BBQ', 'Wednesday-Morning-Go bowling', 'Sunday-Really late at night-Sleep']
```

Note that the `split()` call allows for more than 2 dashes.  Every dash after the second one will be ignored and included in the third part.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use either `sort` or `sorted` providing as the optional  `key` parameter a function that will extract the key you want to sort on. In this case, it is done by splitting the string on the `-` character and pick the last component.

`sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda line: line.rsplit("-", 1)[-1])`

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` function can take a `key` parameter that specifies a function to call on each element before comparing it.

```
def last_part( s ):
    return s.split('-')[-1]

my_strings = ["Wednesday-Morning-Go bowling",
              "Sunday-Really late at night-Sleep",
              "July-Noon-BBQ"]
my_strings.sort( key=last_part )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `key` parameter of `sorted`:

```
>>> L=['Wednesday-Morning-Go bowling','Sunday-Really late at night-Sleep','July-Noon-BBQ']
>>> sorted(L,key=lambda x: x.split('-')[2])
['July-Noon-BBQ', 'Wednesday-Morning-Go bowling', 'Sunday-Really late at night-Sleep']
```